# When running check on an R package, what does the "use ‘--force’ to remove the existing ‘INDEX’" message mean?

Tags: r, testing, package, building

When running `R CMD check` on an R package I often see the following message stating that the INDEX is not up to date:

```
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* checking whether ‘INDEX’ is up-to-date ... NO
* use ‘--force’ to remove the existing ‘INDEX’
* installing the package to re-build vignettes
* creating vignettes ... OK
```

This does not result in an a Warning, Error or even a Note. I assume this is referring to the INDEX file in the top level of the package directory?  How do I "use --force"? I've tried adding `--force` as a argument while building or checking and it just complains that it is not recognized. Is there an R command to rebuild the INDEX file?

Answer (score 2):

Doh, of course I figured it out soon after posting.  This still may be a useful question for other people since I didn't find relevant google hits:

It appears that if the `--force` argument should be given to `R CMD build`  (not INSTALL or check) forcing the INDEX file to be deleted and regenerated.   Also found the R function that generates the INDEX file:

```
tools::Rdindex("man/",outFile="INDEX")
```

Comment: Or just delete the INDEX file and R will automatically build it whenever needed...